# Returning typed List from abstract class becomes non-typed/raw

Tags: java, list, generics, abstract-class

I'm having difficulties returning a typed List. For some reason it is returned as a raw List though I'd really like to get the typed one.

It has to do with the class abstraction. By adding/removing the abstract keyword on the class, my List changes from raw to typed and vice versa. Seems like it's downcasting my generic because of the abstraction?

```
public abstract class Notice<T> {
    public List<Contact> contacts;

    public List<Contact> getContacts()
    {
            return this.contacts;
    }
}


public class Contact {
}

public class Service {
    public Service(Notice notice) {
        // ! Would like to use List<Contact> here, as I defined in Notice !
        List contacts = notice.getContacts();       
    }
}
```

How can I solve this, and why does it happen. I tried Java Generics FAQ etc.

Updated code;
**FacebookMessengerService**

```
public class FacebookMessengerService extends MessengerService<FacebookNotice> {
    public void send(FacebookNotice notice)
    {
        //
        // ERROR occurs here:
        // "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Contact"
        //
        // Also, hovering over it tells me to be just a rawtyped List instead of List<Contact>
        //

        for (Contact contact : notice.getContacts())
        {
            // ..
        }       
    }
}
```

**MessengerService**

```
public abstract class MessengerService<T extends Notice> implements IMessengerService<T> {
}
```

**IMessengerService**

```
public interface IMessengerService<T extends Notice> {
    public void send(T notice);
}
```

**FacebookEventInvitationNotice**

```
public class FacebookEventInvitationNotice extends FacebookNotice<EventInvitation> {    
    public FacebookEventInvitationNotice(EventInvitation trigger) {
        super(trigger);
    }
}
```

**FacebookNotice**

```
public abstract class FacebookNotice<T extends Trigger> extends Notice<T> {
    public static FacebookMessengerService service = new FacebookMessengerService();

    public FacebookNotice(T trigger) {
        super(trigger);
    }


    public void send()
    {
        service.send(this);
    }
}
```

**Notice**

```
public abstract class Notice<T extends Trigger> implements INotice<T> 
{
    public List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    public T trigger;


    public Notice(T trigger)
    {
        this.trigger = trigger;
    }


    public void addContact(Contact contact)
    {
        this.contacts.add(contact);
    }


    public List<Contact> getContacts()
    {
        return this.contacts;
    }
}
```

**INotice**

```
public interface INotice<T extends Trigger> {
    public void send();
}
```

**EventInvitation**

```
public class EventInvitation extends Trigger {
    private Event event;


    public EventInvitation(Event event)
    {
        this.event = event;
    }


    public Event getEvent()
    {
        return this.event;
    }

}
```

**Trigger**

```
public class Trigger {
    public List<Notice> notices = new ArrayList<Notice>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be full generic:

```
public class Service {
    public Service(Notice<?> notice) {
        List<Contact> contacts = notice.getContacts();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `List` to `List<Contact>` in your above code (in Service), and it definitely compiles (I've just verified it). What problem do you have exactly? What's the exact and complete error message of the compiler?

Comment: I repeat. Show us your real code (or at least minimal code that exhibits the problem), and tell us the complete and exact error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: I can see your point, as "public void send(FacebookNotice notice)" is not the right typed signature for "public abstract class FacebookNotice<T extends Trigger>".

Comment: It's surprising, but that's how it is. When you're using a generic type as a raw type, you basically say to the compiler: I don't care about generics here. And everything becomes raw type, even if it doesn't have any relation with the "forgotten" type.

Answer (score 0):

By changing my code as suggested to:

```
public class FacebookMessengerService extends MessengerService<FacebookNotice<?>> {
    public void send(FacebookNotice<?> notice)
    {
        for (Contact contact : notice.getContacts())
        {

        }       
    }
}
```

My problem seems to be solved! Still, I don't see how the difference in `FacebookNotice` and `FacebookNotice<?>` could force my `List<Contact>` to become rawtyped List?